# Delphi destructors: executing code after inherited call?

Tags: delphi, destructor

is it really okay in Delphi to execute code after the inherited call in a destructor?

You can find this in System.Classes:

```
destructor TThread.Destroy;
begin
[...]
  inherited Destroy;
  FFatalException.Free;
end;
```

I think, that accessing an instance member after calling the inherited Destroy method is a bad idea.

Comment: I wouldn't think this is okay.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Actually, this can be very necessary. For example when you need to protect the destructor against exceptions and/or multi-threaded execution. In that case you will almost always have code that executes after the inherited call. It also can be necessary to ensure the life of member instances which serve call backs that can be called from the inherited destructor. IOW: there can be many reasons for this, but I do agree that it is something to look at very, very, very carefully indeed.

Comment: It is as correct as constructing things before the inherited call in the constructor. Not common but valid. Also TThread inherits from TObject so nothing happens in that inherited call anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to execute code *after* a call to an inherited destructor, so long as that code does not rely on something that has been destroyed by that inherited destructor. In the same way it is safe to execute code *before* a call to an inherited constructor, so long as the code does not rely on anything instantiated in that inherited constructor.

But it is certainly true that this is not good style. There are on occasions reasons that would lead you to such code, but usually such reasons should be taken as indication that something is wrong in your design.

In the example that you give there is simply no need to write the code that way. The call to `FFatalException.Free` could perfectly well happen before the call to the inherited destructor.

Answer (score 5):

The instance is not removed from memory by the destructor method itself but by the call of `TObject.FreeInstance`

`TObject.FreeInstance` is called, because a destructor is called, **after** processing the destructor code.

BTW: It is the same to the constructor. The instance is created by `class function TObject.NewInstance : TObject` and it is called **before** the constructor is called (just because it is a constructor)

Because of this, you will have a valid instance inside the whole constructor or destructor code.

Comment: Even after the instance has gone, you can execute code so long as you don't reference the instance

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that is common to all methods, but the question was about a field of the class after inherited and that reference the instance ;o)

Comment: That's the case for the example for sure. I was being a little more general as per *is it really okay in Delphi to execute code after the inherited
call in a destructor?*